# Change MKMapType in MKMapView and keep custom pinImage for annotations

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have set a custom pinImage for my annotations and when I change the type to`MKMapTypeHybrid` it reverts the pinImage setting to the standard pins.

I'm setting the mapType in my `viewWillAppear` method of the map view controller. I'm setting my pinImage for the annotations like so (shortened for clarity):

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *) mapView viewForAnnotation:(id ) annotation {

    MKPinAnnotationView *customAnnotationView=[[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] 
                                            initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                                            reuseIdentifier:@"markerAnnotationView"] autorelease];
    UIImage *pinImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"/pin-image"];
    [customAnnotationView setImage:pinImage];
    return customAnnotationView;
}
```

Is there any way to use `setImage` and set the mapType via code?

Comment: Are you autoreleasing or releasing pinImage anywhere?

Comment: No. Just the inherent autorelease from the 'imageNamed' method. And I added a memory-leaking retain in there just to see if that would solve the disappearing pinImage, but it didn't help.

Comment: Setting the mapType should not affect annotation images.  Showing the full viewForAnnotation code may help.  Does viewWillAppear do anything besides setting the mapType?

Comment: That's pretty much all of the viewForAnnotation code. I took out some code that did some stuff with the annotation (not the annotationView). I've culled it down to just what is shown here and it still has the problem. And I've tried changing the mapType in loadView, viewDidLoad, and in viewWillAppear. All with the same results.

Comment: Not sure if this would cause the issue you're having but even if it's not: You should use dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier in the viewForAnnotation method instead of creating a new view every time.  For a typical viewForAnnotation implementation, see the sample apps MapCallouts or WeatherMap.

Comment: Thanks. That was in there, but took it out to try and boil down the root cause. But good to point out, just in case. At any rate, I found the problem and, as usual with these types of things, I feel kind of like an idiot. I changed from an MKPinAnnotationView to an MKAnnotationView and all works well. I'll add an answer to that effect.

Comment: Excellent! Seems so obvious now--can't believe I missed it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to use an MKAnnotationView instead of the MKPinAnnotationView. I had previously been using the MKPinAnnotationView for good reason but later added a custom image to the pin without changing the instantiating class to MKAnnotationView.

Now, I think it is probably buggy framework behavior. If you're going to let an MKPinAnnotationView accept a setImage call then make sure that it handles it correctly when you change mapTypes. If you only want them to do pins then don't do anything with the call. Ah well.